# MonoTouch crashes when pressing hitting an event

Tags: xamarin.ios

Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/monotouch.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/Mono.Security.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.Core.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /Users/mweel/Projects/MerchantFlo/MerchantFlo/bin/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/MerchantFlo.exe
Could not insert pending breakpoint at 'StartupView.xib.cs:25'. Perhaps the source line does not contain any statements, or the source does not correspond to the current binary.
Could not insert pending breakpoint at 'StartupView.xib.cs:25'. Perhaps the source line does not contain any statements, or the source does not correspond to the current binary.
Resolved pending breakpoint at 'StartupView.xib.cs:25' to Void MerchantFlo.InstanceDelegate:RowSelected ():0.
Stacktrace:

at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0x00004>
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) <0x00004>
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[],string,string) [0x00038] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:26
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/plasma/Source/iphone/monotouch/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:31
  at MerchantFlo.Application.Main (string[]) [0x00000] in /Users/mweel/Projects/MerchantFlo/MerchantFlo/Main.cs:14
  at (wrapper runtime-invoke) .runtime_invoke_void_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr)

Native stacktrace:

```
0   MerchantFlo                         0x000be66f mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 343
1   MerchantFlo                         0x0000e43e mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 313
2   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x90f9146b _sigtramp + 43
3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
4   UIKit                               0x01c4dd50 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 219
5   Foundation                          0x013557f6 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 441
6   CoreFoundation                      0x00df8fe3 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 19
7   CoreFoundation                      0x00dfa594 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 1220
8   CoreFoundation                      0x00d56cc9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1817
9   CoreFoundation                      0x00d56240 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00d56161 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
11  GraphicsServices                    0x03eb6268 GSEventRunModal + 217
12  GraphicsServices                    0x03eb632d GSEventRun + 115
13  UIKit                               0x01bf042e UIApplicationMain + 1160
14  ???                                 0x07f9a72a 0x0 + 133801770
15  ???                                 0x07f9a4fa 0x0 + 133801210
16  ???                                 0x07f99b62 0x0 + 133798754
17  ???                                 0x07f999b4 0x0 + 133798324
18  ???                                 0x07f99a69 0x0 + 133798505
19  MerchantFlo                         0x0000e202 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 1360
20  MerchantFlo                         0x001c92af mono_runtime_invoke + 137
21  MerchantFlo                         0x001caf6b mono_runtime_exec_main + 714
22  MerchantFlo                         0x001ca891 mono_runtime_run_main + 812
23  MerchantFlo                         0x00094fe8 mono_jit_exec + 200
24  MerchantFlo                         0x0027cf05 main + 3494
25  MerchantFlo                         0x00002ca1 _start + 208
26  MerchantFlo                         0x00002bd0 start + 40
```

Debug info from gdb:

warning: Could not find object file "/var/folders/Ny/NyElTwhDGD8kZMqIEeLGXE+++TI/-Tmp-//ccbgiE3V.o" - no debug information available for "template.m".

warning: .o file "/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(zlib-helper.x86.42.o)" more recent than executable timestamp in "/Users/mweel/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/F7026D9A-71FC-4D0E-85B8-9CC956A44022/MerchantFlo.app/MerchantFlo"
warning: Could not open OSO file /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(zlib-helper.x86.42.o) to scan for pubtypes for objfile /Users/mweel/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/F7026D9A-71FC-4D0E-85B8-9CC956A44022/MerchantFlo.app/MerchantFlo
warning: .o file "/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(monotouch-glue.x86.42.o)" more recent than executable timestamp in "/Users/mweel/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/F7026D9A-71FC-4D0E-85B8-9CC956A44022/MerchantFlo.app/MerchantFlo"
warning: Could not open OSO file /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(monotouch-glue.x86.42.o) to scan for pubtypes for objfile /Users/mweel/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/F7026D9A-71FC-4D0E-85B8-9CC956A44022/MerchantFlo.app/MerchantFlo
warning: .o file "/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(gc.x86.42.o)" more recent than executable timestamp in "/Users/mweel/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/F7026D9A-71FC-4D0E-85B8-9CC956A44022/MerchantFlo.app/MerchantFlo"
warning: Could not open OSO file /Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(gc.x86.42.o) to scan for pubtypes for objfile /Users/mweel/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/F7026D9A-71FC-4D0E-85B8-9CC956A44022/MerchantFlo.app/MerchantFlo
warning: .o file "/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(monotouch-glue.x86.42.o)" more recent than executable timestamp in "/Users/mweel/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/F7026D9A-71FC-4D0E-85B8-9CC956A44022/MerchantFlo.app/MerchantFlo"
warning: Couldn't open object file '/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/libmonotouch.a(monotouch-glue.x86.42.o)'
Attaching to process 706.
Reading symbols for shared libraries . done
Reading symbols for shared libraries ...................................................................................................................... done
0x90f36459 in read$UNIX2003 ()
  8                                 0x90f50a12 in __workq_kernreturn ()
  7 "WebThread"                     0x90f2b0fa in mach_msg_trap ()
  6                                 0x90f590a6 in __semwait_signal ()
  5                                 0x90f685fe in recvfrom$UNIX2003 ()
  4                                 0x90f2b136 in semaphore_wait_trap ()
  3                                 0x90f2b0fa in mach_msg_trap ()
  2 "com.apple.libdispatch-manager" 0x90f51982 in kevent ()
* 1 "com.apple.main-thread"         0x90f36459 in read$UNIX2003 ()

Thread 8 (process 706):

## 0  0x90f50a12 in __workq_kernreturn ()

## 1  0x90f50fa8 in _pthread_wqthread ()

## 2  0x90f50bc6 in start_wqthread ()

Thread 7 (process 706):

## 0  0x90f2b0fa in mach_msg_trap ()

## 1  0x90f2b867 in mach_msg ()

## 2  0x00df94a6 in __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort ()

## 3  0x00d56874 in __CFRunLoopRun ()

## 4  0x00d56240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()

## 5  0x00d56161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()

## 6  0x04f7c423 in RunWebThread ()

## 7  0x90f5885d in _pthread_start ()

## 8  0x90f586e2 in thread_start ()

Thread 6 (process 706):

## 0  0x90f590a6 in __semwait_signal ()

## 1  0x90f84ee5 in nanosleep$UNIX2003 ()

## 2  0x90f84e23 in usleep$UNIX2003 ()

## 3  0x0027714c in monotouch_pump_gc ()

## 4  0x90f5885d in _pthread_start ()

## 5  0x90f586e2 in thread_start ()

Thread 5 (process 706):

## 0  0x90f685fe in recvfrom$UNIX2003 ()

## 1  0x90f883c7 in recv$UNIX2003 ()

## 2  0x000d8cca in recv_length (fd=6, buf=0xb0388ebd, len=11, flags=0) at ../../../../mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:939

## 3  0x000e616a in debugger_thread (arg=0x0) at ../../../../mono/mini/debugger-agent.c:6290

## 4  0x002448e2 in thread_start_routine (args=0x706c1a8) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/wthreads.c:286

## 5  0x00274357 in GC_start_routine (arg=0x6ff6f60) at ../../../libgc/pthread_support.c:1390

## 6  0x90f5885d in _pthread_start ()

## 7  0x90f586e2 in thread_start ()

Thread 4 (process 706):

## 0  0x90f2b136 in semaphore_wait_trap ()

## 1  0x0015ae1d in finalizer_thread (unused=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/gc.c:1026

## 2  0x002034a3 in start_wrapper (data=0x6e30e70) at ../../../../mono/metadata/threads.c:661

## 3  0x002448e2 in thread_start_routine (args=0x706c0b0) at ../../../../mono/io-layer/wthreads.c:286

## 4  0x00274357 in GC_start_routine (arg=0x6ff6f60) at ../../../libgc/pthread_support.c:1390

## 5  0x90f5885d in _pthread_start ()

## 6  0x90f586e2 in thread_start ()

Thread 3 (process 706):

## 0  0x90f2b0fa in mach_msg_trap ()

## 1  0x90f2b867 in mach_msg ()

## 2  0x0011cc46 in mach_exception_thread (arg=0x0) at ../../../../mono/mini/mini-darwin.c:138

## 3  0x90f5885d in _pthread_start ()

## 4  0x90f586e2 in thread_start ()

Thread 2 (process 706):

## 0  0x90f51982 in kevent ()

## 1  0x90f5209c in _dispatch_mgr_invoke ()

## 2  0x90f51559 in _dispatch_queue_invoke ()

## 3  0x90f512fe in _dispatch_worker_thread2 ()

## 4  0x90f50d81 in _pthread_wqthread ()

## 5  0x90f50bc6 in start_wqthread ()

Thread 1 (process 706):

## 0  0x90f36459 in read$UNIX2003 ()

## 1  0x000be81f in mono_handle_native_sigsegv (signal=11, ctx=0xbfffdaf4) at ../../../../mono/mini/mini-exceptions.c:1826

## 2  0x0000e43e in mono_sigsegv_signal_handler (_dummy=11, info=0xbfffdab4, context=0xbfffdaf4) at ../../../../mono/mini/mini.c:4846

## 3

## 4  0x028d6a67 in objc_msgSend ()

## 5  0x06eeb470 in ?? ()

## 6  0x01c4dd50 in -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] ()

## 7  0x013557f6 in __NSFireDelayedPerform ()

## 8  0x00df8fe3 in **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** ()

## 9  0x00dfa594 in __CFRunLoopDoTimer ()

## 10 0x00d56cc9 in __CFRunLoopRun ()

## 11 0x00d56240 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()

## 12 0x00d56161 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()

## 13 0x03eb6268 in GSEventRunModal ()

## 14 0x03eb632d in GSEventRun ()

## 15 0x01bf042e in UIApplicationMain ()

## 16 0x07f9a72a in ?? ()

## 17 0x07f9a4fa in ?? ()

## 18 0x07f99b62 in ?? ()

## 19 0x07f999b4 in ?? ()

## 20 0x07f99a69 in ?? ()

## 21 0x0000e202 in mono_jit_runtime_invoke (method=0x71d9fbc, obj=0x0, params=0xbfffedec, exc=0x0) at ../../../../mono/mini/mini.c:4733

## 22 0x001c92af in mono_runtime_invoke (method=0x71d9fbc, obj=0x0, params=0xbfffedec, exc=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/object.c:2615

## 23 0x001caf6b in mono_runtime_exec_main (method=0x71d9fbc, args=0x9f24460, exc=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/object.c:3581

## 24 0x001ca891 in mono_runtime_run_main (method=0x71d9fbc, argc=0, argv=0xbfffef24, exc=0x0) at ../../../../mono/metadata/object.c:3355

## 25 0x00094fe8 in mono_jit_exec (domain=0x6f91e58, assembly=0x6ed2e20, argc=1, argv=0xbfffef20) at ../../../../mono/mini/driver.c:1094

## 26 0x0027cf05 in main ()

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries

## used by your application.

Comment: Don't expect anyone to help you find anything from a crash report, zero code, zero explanations of the context, and zero explanations of what you tried.

Comment: I agree with zneak. Provide some code and a description.

Comment: I think you just threw up on my browser.

Comment: I dont know what else to say.  Any time I touch on an  event on a table it blows up with this stack trace.  Even when I dont have a delegate attached.

Answer (score 1):

I'm willing to bet that the problem is that you have a UIViewController or a button, that is defined within the scope of a method, like your Main, not realizing that it will present before being garbage collected and then, as soon as you do anything, it crashes like this.

I've had it happen a couple of times.